# Change form dynamically in django

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

There's a way to load a django form trough ajax? Let's say an user needs to change a form depending on what he want. First a form with a choicefield and a decimalfield appears. Then ,depending on the value of the choicefield, an ajax request to a view can change it to another form or stay the same:

forms.py

```
a_choices = (
("a", "A"),
("b", "B"),
("c", "C"),
)

d_choices = (
("d", "D"),
("e", "E"),
)


class simpleForm(forms.Form):
    #this is the first form
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('method')
        super(simpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["chosen_method"].choices = choices

    chosen_method = forms.ChoiceField(label="Método")
    simple_variable = forms.DecimalField()

class complexForm(simpleForm):

    second_variables = forms.DecimalField()
    third_variable = forms.DecimalField()
```

I try an ajax way like this, who watches the choicefield value (#id_chosen_method) for a change:

ajax_form.js

```
(function ($) {
explanation = function () {
    $("#id_chosen_method").change(function () {
        var election = $("#id_chosen_method").val();
        // Add or remove fields depending of method chosen
        $.getJSON("/form2/" + election + "/", function (data) {
            if (data)
            {
                $("#form_fields").html(data.form);
                $("#explanation_text").html(data.explanation);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#form_fields").html("no form!");
                $("#explanation_text").html("no explanation!");
            }
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Finally the url and the view who get the "method" argument passed by the javascript function:

```
#url.py
url(r'^/form2/(?P<method>\w+)/$', ajax_form, name='ajax_form'),

#views.py
def ajax_form(request, method):

    import json
    from app.forms import simpleForm, complexForm
    from app.otherFile import explanations

    if request.is_ajax:
        form_choices = (("a", "b", "c",),("f", "g"))
        if method in form_choices[0]:
            if method == form_choices[0][-1]:
                form = simpleForm(method=a_choices)
            else:
                form = simpleForm(method=d_choices)
        else:
            if method == form_choices[1][1]:
                form = complexForm(method=a_choices)
            else:
                form = complexForm(method=d_choices)

        explanation = explanations[method]
        data = {"form": form, "explanation": explanation}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/javascript")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

So the final idea is the user choosing what form wants depending on the val of the choicefield showed in the first place. But i can't get this to work. Am i missing something? there's a better way to handle things like this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a base form class, and have two different forms inherit from the base one. You can load a different form via ajax depending on user input. You can probably even use the same template for the form. Your view would have something like

```
form=simpleFormA()
```

and

```
form=simpleFormB()
```

based on what 'method' is. forms.py would change to something like this:

```
_a_choices = (
("a", "A"),
("b", "B"),
("c", "C"),
)

_d_choices = (
("d", "D"),
("e", "E"),
)


class simpleForm(forms.Form):
    # this is the first form
    # all other fields here
    simple_variable = forms.DecimalField()

class simpleFormA(simpleForm):
    chosen_method = forms.ChoiceField(label="Método", choices=_a_choices)

class simpleFormB(simpleForm):
    chosen_method = forms.ChoiceField(label="Método", choices=_b_choices)
```

Make sense?

Comment: When i call simpleFormA it raises a 
`Caught NameError while rendering: name 'self' is not defined`
in forms.py line :
`self.fields["chosen_method"].choices = _a_choices`

Comment: This thread helped me solve a problem I was trying to figure out on my own for the past day.  Thank you guys!